# React Native flexBox footer does not work

Tags: react-native

I searched how to set footer using React Native.
and I found a solution

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31249011/8226957

I followed and put `style={{flex: 1}}` to root View, but it does not work.

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <ScrollView>
        <FlatList
            data={this.state.datas}
            renderItem={({item}) =>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this._deleteKeyFromAsyncStorage(item.key)}}>
                    <Text style={styles.item}>
                        {item.value}
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            }
        />
    </ScrollView>
    <View>
        <TextInput
            style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
            onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
            value={this.state.text}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onAddButton}>
            <View style={{
                height: 50,
                backgroundColor: 'steelblue',
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
            }}>
                <Text style={{textAlign: 'auto'}}>ADD</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
</View>
```

when I follow that, I see disappeared List.

Comment: can you add a quick sketch of what you want it to look like? or an example from another app

Comment: @RyanTurnbull I want textInput and Button (footer) are fixed at the bottom of screen. https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnheG.png (like this)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `justifyContent : 'space-between'` and add `flexDirection: 'column'` that should be fix your problem

```
<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap the `<ScrollView>` in a `<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>`

If that does not work, try to set a fixed height too your footer: `<View style={{ height: 90 }}>`