# Fixed footer in react native with FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29447715/react-native-fixed-footer) on fixed footer with a ScrollView, I'm trying to implement a fixed footer on the screen with a [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html). I have tried to use the answer provided by putting the flat list inside a view, but then none of the items are rendered. Does any one know how to implement a fixed footer with a flat list as the other main element of component?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Using this [flex solution](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/364#issuecomment-87071334) I managed to do it with a couple of nested Views:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <View style={{flex: 0.9}}>
    <FlatList/>
  </View>
  <View style={{flex: 0.1}}/>
</View>
```

Comment: could you remove the first child `<View/>` and provide the `{{flex: 0.9}}` value passed into the `contentContainerStyle` prop of this FlatList to achieve the same result?

Comment: I tried that, but it won't work @kinghenry14. Unsure why.

Answer (score 6):

It is similar to the answer above, but I think this also works.

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <FlatList/>
  </View>
  <View />
</View>
```

Answer (score 5):

FlatList comes with footer support in the form of `ListFooterComponent`

Try adding something like this to your flatlist

`ListFooterComponent={() => <Text>Footer content</Text>}`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As far as I understand the docs at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#listfootercomponent, this is to specify something that is rendered at the bottom of _all_ the items and not at the bottom of the screen...

Comment: `ListFooterComponent` only renders once but it doesn't have a *sticky* option.

Answer (score 3):

To complete the solution of Tom and avoid a gap/space at the bottom of the screen.

Use an integer for `flex` value

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <FlatList/>
  </View>
  <View style={{flex: 0}}/>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

This also worked for me to keep the button at the bottom while allowing `FlatList` to work properly:

```
<View style={{
  display: 'flex',
}}>
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <FlatList
      data={data}
      renderItem={() => <Item/>}
    />
  </View>
  <View style={{ marginTop: 'auto'}}>
    <Btn/>
  </View>
</View>
```

`marginTop: auto` will push the button to the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer does work, but you can also have the flatlist **grow** and let footer take up the space it needs:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <View style={{flex: 1, flexGrow: 1}}>
    <FlatList/>
  </View>
  <Button>Anything here</Button>
</View>
```

[Snack demo here](https://snack.expo.dev/boVU69JVW)

[image: Example]