# How to implement a sticky header in inverted FlatList?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

I am using Flatlist to show my items in a list. Now the problem is that whenever the screen loads. It should show the last item. For this, I have used the inverted property of the Flatlist. But the problem is that now my sticky header of the Flatlist is at the end of the Flatlist that is after the items. It is looking like the footer. How can I implement a sticky header in the inverted Flatlist.

Comment: What about using ListFooterComponent instead of ListHeaderComponent ?

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49224471/fixed-footer-in-react-native-with-flatlist can help?

Comment: Hi, @monsty I have tried ListFooterComponent, but it does not stick at the top. Thanks