# Absolute positioned Icon inside ScrollView moves along with other contents

Tags: react-native

I want to fix an icon inside <ScrollView at right bottom as shown below

[image]

But currently , the + icon is moving along with other contents. I want it to be fixed at that position even when other contents go down in the background. Current behaviour
[image: Current behaviour]

Tried solution :

I used contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow :1}} in the ScrollView , still it doesnt work .
It works when I add the icon outside ScrollView. But it doesn't give expected results which is shown below it cuts the scrolliew content right above the icon:

[image]

Can anyone suggest with good solution for this scenario?

Code :

```
<ScrollView>
          {this.state.alertData &&
            this.state.alertData.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <View>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.alertContainer}
                    onPress={() => this.onCardClick(index, true)}
                  >
                    <View
                      style={{
                        flexDirection: "row",
                        justifyContent: "space-between",
                      }}
                    >
                      <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
                      <View
                        style={{
                          flexDirection: "row",
                        }}
                      >
                        <Text style={styles.sideText}>Il y a 2h</Text>
                        {item.status && (
                          <Away style={{ marginLeft: 5, marginTop: 6 }} />
                        )}
                      </View>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
                      <Text style={styles.primaryText}>{item.primaryText}</Text>
                      <Text style={styles.secondaryText}>
                        {item.secondaryText}
                      </Text>
                    </View>
                    <View>
                      <Text style={styles.primaryText}>Message</Text>
                      <Text style={styles.secondaryText}>{item.message}</Text>
                    </View>
                    {this.state.selectedCard[index] && (
                      <Image
                        style={{ height: 250, width: 300 }}
                        // source={require("../../../assets/images/image6.jpeg")}
                        source={item.image}
                      />
                    )}
                  </TouchableOpacity>

                  <Close
                    style={{ top: 10, right: -5, position: "absolute" }}
                    onPress={() => this.toggleModal(index)}
                  />
                </View>
              );
            })}

          <View
            style={{ alignItems: "flex-end", marginTop: 20, marginBottom: 20 }}
          >
            <AddnewAlerts />
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
```

Comment: From an iOS point of view... if you place something in a scrollview it is because you want it to scroll. The "absolute" positions inside the scroll view are relative to the scroll offset. In order to do this in iOS I would place the button outside the scroll view but overlapping it. Include more code from what you are doing, it will help people help you.

Comment: I wanted this for android Phone

Comment: The concept would still be the same for Android I believe. Inside a scroll view you are working with "absolute" positions that will change on the screen based on the scroll view's offset. If you want something to not move then don't place it in the scroll view.

Comment: I agree with @Fogmeister. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29447715/react-native-fixed-footer for reference.

Comment: just put that out side of scrollView then i hope u will find you answer.

Comment: If i put Icon outside scrollview the result is not as expected. I have attached an image at the end with a red circle for unexpected behavior

Comment: Ah, it seems what you have got is some sort of layout device which is laying out the scrollview and the + button next to each other. You need to place the + button **over** the scrollview. Not alongside it and not in it but stacked in the z-axis over it. Here is a question about overlapping views in React Native... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47545355/how-to-overlap-in-react-native Apologies, I can't help much more than this as I am not familiar with the minute details of React Native. I am answering this from a native iOS developer :)